How to calculate the 0 g offset of an accelerometer versus the upper and lower temperature limits?
I'm verifying the Bosch SMI230 accelerometer, and the documentation states that the zero-g offset temperature drift is ±0.2 mg/K. I want to calculate the upper and lower limit values for the 0 g offset. For example, at -20°C, the upper limit is -20 * 0.002 g? And at 80°C, the upper limit is 80 * 0.002 g?
Figure 1 shows my test data, where I tested the zero-g offset of the sensor in a temperature chamber from -20°C to 85°C.
Another question is whether I should verify the upper and lower limits of the 0 g offset versus temperature, or if I only need to ensure that the acceleration values do not exceed the zero-g offset (including temperature) of 20 mg between -20°C and 85°C?



From the datasheet, this is the relevant specification:

The upper and lower limits are stated to be +/-20mg.
The temperature drift specification is only valid over the "full temperature range", which is -40C to +105C. The usual interpretation of such a spec is that if draw a box that encloses the highest and lowest offset (Y-axis) and has a width of the full temperature range that all offsets observed will be within that box. It might fluctuate up and down within that box (which you are indeed observing)- there is no guarantee that it is monotonic nor that the slope of mg offset per degree will not exceed +/0.2.
So if it never exceeds +/-20mg and the height of the 'box' is smaller than 29mg it is within specifications.
Of course you'll have to use a test procedure that eliminates the effect of gravity. I believe there is a relevant standard.

29mg?  Isn’t it +/-20mg?

145 degrees multiplied by the  +/-0.2
